# CGContextDrawImage crashes with odd width value

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, core-graphics, cgimage

I try to draw a CGImageRef with CGContextDrawImage on Mac OSX Yosemite. 
When my image has even width everything works well, but when it is odd the program crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, even if everything seems OK (image and bitmapContext are in memory).

Here is my code :

```
unsigned long rowBytes = ((CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image) * CGImageGetWidth(image)) + 15) & ~15;

/* TRIED THIS WITH SAME RESULTS
unsigned long rowBytes = CGImageGetWidth(image) * 4;

if (rowBytes % 16) {

    rowBytes = ((rowBytes / 16) + 1) * 16;

}
*/

void *baseAddress = valloc(CGImageGetHeight(image) * rowBytes);

if (baseAddress == NULL) {

    CGImageRelease(image);

    return nil;

}

CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress,
                                                   CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                                   CGImageGetHeight(image),
                                                   8,
                                                   rowBytes,
                                                   [context colorSpace],
                                                   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host);


if (bitmapContext == NULL) {

    free(baseAddress);
    CGImageRelease(image);

    return nil;

}


CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image));
CGContextClearRect(bitmapContext, bounds);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, bounds, image);
```

When the crash appears, the libRIP library seems to be involved with these messages:

> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff8124aaa0 decode_byte_8bpc_3 +
>   375 1   com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff8123a2af decode_data
>   + 19394 2   com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff81234c84 img_decode_read + 380 3   com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff812349ff img_colormatch_read + 379 4
>   com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff8121a40d img_data_lock + 8512
>   5   com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff8121726e CGSImageDataLock
>   + 151 6   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00007fff8c8d52d2 ripc_AcquireImage + 906 7   libRIP.A.dylib
>     0x00007fff8c8d3df5 ripc_DrawImage + 1037 8   com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff81216e27 CGContextDrawImage + 457

I thought this was a row bytes value problem but every attempt to manage with this value fails. 
Does anyone had the same issue and resolved it ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Your current computation `((CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image) * CGImageGetWidth(image)) + 15) & ~15` calculates the **bits**-per-row, not the bytes. In any case, unless you're trying to force a particular bytes-per-row, you should pass `NULL` for the `data` parameter and 0 for the `bytesPerRow` parameter of `CGBitmapContextCreate()` so that it manages the buffer and computes the optimal bytes-per-row. Finally, from the stack trace, I suspect the problem is with the source image, not the bitmap context. CG may have deferred using the data for that until it was drawn, so a problem would happen then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have an image named `image` and the first thing you do is to compute the numbers of byte in a row. You should **never** do this yourself! Only the image itself knows how many bytes it uses for a row. `CGimage` and friends have there own strategy to define this number and it may (and it did) change from from OS version to the next. Ask the **image** directly:

```
unsigned long rowBytes = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image);
```

Try this and see if the result of your code and my hint are different.

I am not shure if this will kill the crusher. Give it a try.

Comment: I thought the bytes per row had to be multiple of 16... Well, getting the bytes per row directly from the image doesn't make it work neither.